# How to disable widget tree printing in flutter CLI (Pressing "T" key accidently is annoying)

Tags: flutter, terminal

I accidentally press the key "T" in terminal when I reach to "R" to hot reload and always my app's widget tree is printed and it takes minutes to finish so It annoyes me so much. I really need to turn this feature off if it's possible but I don't know how.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope, I started to think that most people doesn't use terminal or doesn't make mistake as we do or they wait for it like a psychopath

Comment: here, you should have clear idea how to customize your terminal workflow. let me know if you have any more questions

Answer (score 7):

TLDR:

comment out line 1285 - 1291 in

`flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/resident_runner.dart`

commit changes in your local flutter git repo and 't' will be disabled.

---

This happens inside

`flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/resident_runner.dart`

in

`Future<bool> _commonTerminalInputHandler(String character)`

method.

It is handled here

```
case 't':
      case 'T':
        if (residentRunner.supportsServiceProtocol) {
          await residentRunner.debugDumpRenderTree();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
```

and the only check if in `supportsServiceProtocol` getter which returns true if the app is in debug or profile mode.

If that check goes true, the method is called in VirtualMachine

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> flutterDebugDumpRenderTree() {
    return invokeFlutterExtensionRpcRaw('ext.flutter.debugDumpRenderTree');
  }
```

and that handles the output. So unfortunately, you cannot disable this without changing the flutter source code.

Fortunately for you, changing the flutter source code is super easy.

Go inside `flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/resident_runner.dart` and comment out the cases that you don't want to trigger.

```
      case 'S':
        if (residentRunner.supportsServiceProtocol) {
          await residentRunner.debugDumpSemanticsTreeInTraversalOrder();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
//      case 't':
//      case 'T':
//        if (residentRunner.supportsServiceProtocol) {
//          await residentRunner.debugDumpRenderTree();
//          return true;
//        }
//        return false;
```

So you have successfully changed flutter source.
Now you need to rebuild flutter tools.

To do that, you can follow [developer docs](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/The-flutter-tool#making-changes-to-the-flutter-tool):

> If you want to alter and re-test the tool's behavior itself, locally commit your tool change in git and the tool will be rebuilt from Dart sources in `packages/flutter_tools` the next time you run flutter. Alternatively, delete the `bin/cache/flutter_tools.snapshot` file. Doing so will force a rebuild of the tool from your local sources the next time you run flutter.

To put it simple, open the terminal in flutter root and commit your changes.
Next time you run the `flutter run` you will see message output in terminal:

`Building flutter tool...`

When you want to upgrade flutter, run `git pull --rebase` and your changes will be saved.